# Some zip archives prompted as invalid by windows explorer Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, 7-zip

Some zip files cannot be opened by built-in Windows 10 Explorer. The archive can be opened and extracted by 7-zip app without issues.

That is kind of strange issue because windows explorer works fine with all archives but not this one.

Any ideas? The archive in question is kind of large (about 12GB) so sadly I can not provide it here. At first I thought it is about archive size. But other even bigger archives opened fine with Windows Explorer.

Can it be the problem with long or forbidden characters file names or maybe multilayered folder structure inside this archive?

Comment: Giving more information on "cannot be opened" would have been helpful to us (error messages etc.), I see you solved it.

Comment: That was literally what Explorer say "Windows can not open the folder. The compressed (zipped) folder is invalid" .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the root of the problem. Found one file with extra long filename and archive can not be opened.